# Code Igniter and Browser Compatibility

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-plugins

This might be inappropriate question to be asked here. I have been stuck with the problems for long time. I have build CI project that have different Jquery PLugins. The project runs properly in Firefox and Chrome but it appears mess in the IE even in latest version. I have test Jquery plugins without integrating in CI and it displays properly in IE. But When I use that Jquery plugins in Code Igniter it doesn't display properly. The Slider Jquery Plugins doesn't display properly in IE.

My question is here that Does Code Igniter also make difference displaying the page in different browser?

Comment: Please post relevant code and we can help.

Comment: I have already solved the problem. I have updated the query library to latest now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply problem is in jquery integrating in to Codeigniter framework. This framework uses MVC designing pattern. Framework is pure PHP. So if it doesn't work jquery in your web site, it is a problem with integrating jquery in to  CI.

Probly, you might have not use `base_url()` properly in the framework or may not set correct path to jquery libraries or not included related files in the web. please check above and if it wouldn't work, post the code that set jquery.